# Is it true that every prime ideal of height one is principal?

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, ideals

> Is it true that every prime ideal of height one is principal ?

Please help

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1186419/is-a-height-one-ideal-in-a-ufd-principal

Comment: is every principal prime ideal height 1?

Comment: No, that is something different

Comment: @JonMarkPerry $(0)$ is not height 1 in a domain and is principal (and prime).  I think what you are looking for is Krull's principal ideal theorem.  In a Noetherian ring, any principal proper ideal has rank at most 1.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Krull%27s_principal_ideal_theorem

Comment: Rank one valuation domains are not necessarily noetherian, so their maximal ideal can be even infinitely generated.

Comment: Exactly.  Strange stuff happens when rings are not Noetherian, but that makes them fun to study!

Answer (score 2):

Any Dedekind domain is dimension one, but not all Dedekind domains are PID's.  For instance $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$ is a standard example.  The ideal $(2,1+\sqrt{-5})$ is maximal and therefore prime and is not the zero ideal, so it has rank $1$, but is not principal.