# $\dim R = n-1$ if and only if $ R\cong k[x_1,\dots,x_n]/(f) $

Tags: commutative-algebra

> Let $k$ be a field and $R$ a $k$-algebra generated by $ n<\infty $ elements. Show that the following are equivalent:
>
> (i) $R$ is a domain of dimension $ n-1 $
>
> (ii) $ R\cong k[x_1,\dots,x_n]/(f) $ where $ k[x_1,\dots,x_n] $  is a polynomial ring and $f$ an irreducible polynomial.

I am at a loss here. Hilbert's Nullstellensatz seems like it should apply, but I'm not sure how.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Loosely speaking, this says that the dimension drops by $1$ if and only if we cut out a single equation. Note that this is false, if we drop the domain hypothesis. For instance look at $k[x,y]/(x^2,xy)$. This cannot be cut out by one polynomial, since it is not Cohen-Macaulay.

---

To proof your statement, note that (ii) implies (i) by Krull's principal ideal theorem.

The other direction is a consequence of two things:

(a) dimension theory of affine $k$-algebras, in particular the statement that dimension and co-dimension behave well, i.e. the height and the co-height of a prime ideal add up to the dimension of the ring.

(b) In a [UFD, height one prime ideals](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0AFT) are principal. [Note that this is wrong for arbitrary height one ideals](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1186419/is-a-height-one-ideal-in-a-ufd-principal), so the proof fails without the domain assumption.

Using this, we can argue as follows: By assumption, $R \cong k[x_1, \dotsc, x_n]/I$ for some prime ideal $I$. Using (a) and $\dim R=n-1$, we get $\operatorname{height} I = 1$, i.e. $I$ is principal by (b). Hence $R=k[x_1, \dotsc, x_n]/(f)$.

---

Note that (b) is just a very small lemma which can be prove in two lines, but (a) is a very basic fact and one of the kickstarters of classical algebraic geometry. One has to work for this a bit and it is not trivial. One usually uses Noether normalization to show this. You can find a reference in almost any book on commutative algebra or algebraic geometry.